# Attempting to use worksheetfunction in userform?

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I have a free form text box, which I'd like to populate with a value once a value is inputted in an above text box (txtStore) <-based on a 4 digit number.

here is the code I've attempted, but not sure if other subs (boolean logic) is needed to trigger something?

```
Dim ws as worksheet
Private Sub txtMall_Change()
    Set ws = Worksheets("Lists")
    Dim txtStore As Integer: txtStore = Me.txtStore.Value
    txtMall.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.IfError(VLookup(txtStore, ws.Range("A2:B1047", 2, False)), "-")
End Sub
```

how can I get the txtMall to populate based on that worksheet function once a value is placed in the txtStore text input? Do I need to change the procedure to something else like I'd have to with a combobox?

Comment: You can't just use `Vlookup`, it has to be `WorksheetFunction.VLookup` or `Application.VLookup`.

Comment: Also you can't use `IfError()` in VBA

Comment: @BigBen so, `Application.WorksheetFunction.vlookup(txtStore, ws.Range("A2:B1047", 2, False))` should work fine?

Comment: No because your parentheses are off for the `ws.Range` call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Untested:

```
Private Sub txtStore_Change()
    Dim r
    'Avoid possible run-time error on no match by skipping WorksheetFunction
    '  Instead test the return value for errors 
    r = Application.VLookup(CLng(Me.txtStore.Value), _
                            Worksheets("Lists").Range("A2:B1047"), 2, False)
    txtMall.Value = IIf(iserror(r), "'-", r)
End Sub
```

Comment: logistically speaking, I don't see why this wouldn't work, but I'm populating a 4 digit number while running the form in `txtStore` and it's not  populating anything underneath in `txtMall`

Comment: "1111" is not the same as 1111 when it comes to lookups.  See edit above.

Comment: nothing is happening with that either, do I need to update the procedural context to something else other than `change`?

Comment: Edited - should be `txtStore_Change` not `txtMall_Change`

Comment: ok, so now when I type in a number, I get the `-`, which shows its being executed. For instance, I typed in 2565, and it exists as a general value on the lookup sheet, but it's still only populating `-`. Also, when i backspace completely to 0 characters, I get an application defined error (guessing I can do an on error resume next for that).

Comment: Don't use On Error Resume Next - just test to see if `Me.txtStore.Value` is non-zero length and numeric.

Comment: Try dropping the `CLng()`

Comment: I was inputting the wrong lookup sheet, it's working now. Appreciate the help a ton!